# Formula for sum of first n Odious number

Tags: sequences-and-series

I searched for the formula for sum of first n Odious number, I found this on OEIS (A173209)

> $a(n) = n^2 - n/2 + O(1)$

What does the term $O(1)$ mean?
I tried putting in values for several values of $n$, it gives correct result but sometimes the result is $1$ greater than the correct result.

Comment: This is $O$-notation. Here $O(1)$ just means a bounded function.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown can you elaborate 'bounded function'?
Also why for some values of n the result is 1 more than the correct result?

Comment: To be more precise $O(1)$ basically means there is some some number $K$ such that $ a(n) \le n^2 - \frac{n}{2} + K  \ \forall  \ n  \ \ge 1$, $O(1)$ is used to say with ease "there is a cosntant, what exactly it is, isn't so important"

Comment: that helps, thanks @frogeyedpeas

Comment: The important aspect is that $O(1)$ stands for a constant that is **independent of n**. So the maximal deviation of $a(n)$ and $n^2-n/2$ is some $K$ for any $n$. It doesn't say anything about the value though, $K$ could be 1 (as you observe) but it might as well be a million. It only says it doesn't grow with $n$.